# The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_24 was killed

Tags: android-studio

I have a problems with my AVD. When I try to create a virtual emulator and run it these error pops out:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4
emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\chuba\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_24.avd/userdata.img
No accelerator found.
failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument



Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_24 was killed
```

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me as well, what fixed it:
Check if Intel HAXM is correctly installed!

**Go to:** 
C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

**Install:**
intelhaxm-android.exe

Then try again.

Answer (score 1):

It is about HAX!

easy to solve:

1. in android studio, go to tools -> SDK manager
2. find and delete HAX from there
3. open AVD manager
4. let android studio to install it again.

These problems occur when a new version is available!