# When ever I launch my AVD, it gets killed itself

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When ever I launch my AVD, it gets killed itself. It shows the message

> `The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_23 was killed.`

In the event logs:

> `Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135).`

I have tried almost everything. I have installed Intelx86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM). I have also installed the SDK platforms. My virtualization is enabled in BIOS. But it still isn't working for me.

Comment: Try another AVD

Comment: Did you try reinstalling HAXM? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766060/2350083

Answer (score 0):

1.This link may help you.
[ERROR Android emulator gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed)

2.And you can try this way:
find `Settings\System Settings\Android SDK` then click `Optimize disk space`

3.or this way:
find Android Studio → File → Settings → System Settings → Android SDK → SDK Tools → Intel x86 then select HAXM and apply settings.

But when I encounter such problems, I always delete this AVD and replace it with a new one.

Comment: i tried this also but it dose not worked. I have created several AVDs but none of them is running.

Comment: @AbhishekKumarSingh try this way: find Android Studio → File → Settings → System Settings → Android SDK → SDK Tools → Intel x86  then select  HAXM and apply settings.

Comment: @AbhishekKumarSingh  I'm glad to hear your good news. I added this useful way in my answer you can accepted my answer so that my reputation will be added~Thanks.